# C# undefine project wide preprocessor

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a C# project that has some solution wide defines in *Conditional compilation symbols*, see here
[image]

I now want to unit test that code and I need to undefine some of those variables.
For Unit testing I have a xUnit project that references the solution with the defines.

Is it possible in VS2019 to disable those defines?

**Edit**
In my specific case I have a Unity project added to my solution. Unity has Unity-specific code that cannot be executed in unit tests such like xUnit.

In order to cope with that, I wrap Unity-specific code (like Logging via `Debug.Log`) into a define `UNITY_2020` that is automatically defined by the Unity project-file.

Now on the unit test side I want to undefine said preprocessor `UNITY_2020`. As I have the source code (no DLL or nuget), I hope that there is a way to compile and run my unit tests without having troubles with Unity-specific code.

So far, putting `#undef UNTIY_2020` at the top of my test files does not help.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The property page you're showing in your post goes with a _project_, not a Solution file. It's also unclear whether you are asking about an assembly that's already compiled, nor why the xUnit project would be affected by the defined symbols. You can use `#undef` to undefine symbols, but only at compile time and only in the specific assembly being compiled. There's nothing in your question that suggests that would actually work for you. Please clarify the question.

Comment: You are correct, it should state C# project in a solution, I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Disable" is not quite the correct terminology, but that's ok. It is possible to undefine symbols by using the `#undef` preprocessor directive. You can read about it on [C# preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives).

For example, you can place an `#undef` at the top of a file (actually anywhere really):

```
#undef CSHARP_7_OR_LATER
...
#if !CSHARP7_OR_LATER
// some code that can now be tested...
#endif
```

Also, preprocessor symbols apply to files (technically, to a compilation unit), and just happen to be commonly defined (or not) in your `.csproj`. At compile-time, these and passed to the compiler. So... they are not solution-wide unless you define them for *all* of the projects.

If the referenced projects are referenced via assembly or NuGet references, you will not be able to affect the compiled code, because, well, it's already compiled.

If, instead, you are referencing the projects directly, or the code directly (e.g. with add or add link) you can either modify the files as I stated, or you could create a new build configuration for each project and the solution, and then define (or not) the preprocessor symbols there.

Comment: in my specific case I have a Unity project that generates a `csproj` file that I include in VS2019. I want to unit test my Unity code with xUnit, but I have troubles with xUnit running Unity-specific code, so I wrap all Unity specific code in a define and it runs nice in Unity. I do not want my unit test to run this code, so I want to undefine the wrapper around Unity-specific code, so my unit tests can run.

Comment: @user3079834 Yeah, then I suggest you might want Debug, Release and Test build configurations. In  Test, you would not define the symbols, but in the other configs you would.

Comment: The build configuration did the trick. I just hope Unity doesn't rewrite the `csproj` too often and thereby deletes the new build configuration.